# How do I get Unicode to show up in C++ RICHEDIT_CLASS?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, sendmessage, richedit

I have been trying and researching all day non-stop and have tried everything I found, but nothing seems to work for me.

I am pretty sure it is a problem somewhere in here:

```
void edit_append (const char *text)
{
    CHARRANGE range = {-1, -1};
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&range);
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)text);
}
```

If you need any other of my code I would be happy to paste it here, I have been fighting with it all day. When I SendMessage() Unicode I just get weird symbols and one time I even got a bunch of question marks.

Comment: Use UTF-16 encoding and WCHAR (alias wchar_t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `char*` to `EM_REPLACESEL`.  That will only work if your RichEdit control is using an Ansi HWND via `CreateWindow(Ex)A(RICHEDIT_CLASSA)`.  If it is using a Unicode HWND via `CreateWindow(Ex)W(RICHEDIT_CLASSW)`, you need to pass a `wchar_t*` instead:

```
void edit_append (const wchar_t *text)
{
    CHARRANGE range = {-1, -1};
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&range);
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)text);
}

void edit_clear (void)
{
    CHARRANGE range = {0, -1};
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&range);
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)L"");
}
```

If you cannot change the data type for `text` for whatever reason, then you will have to use `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivilent) to convert the data to UTF-16 before giving it to `SendMessage()`:

```
void edit_append (const char *text)
{
    int len = strlen(text);
    int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, text, len, NULL, 0);

    wchar_t *wtext = new wchar_t[wlen+1];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, text, len, wtext, wlen);
    wtext[wlen] = 0;

    CHARRANGE range = {-1, -1};
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&range);
    SendMessage(win_log, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)wtext);

    delete[] wtext;
}
```

Comment: This is my window: `win_log = CreateWindow(RICHEDIT_CLASS, NULL,
                               WS_GROUP | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | ES_DISABLENOSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_SUNKEN, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, win_main, NULL, hInstance, NULL);`

Comment: Both `CreateWindow()` and `RICHEDIT_CLASS` are preprocessor macros that are sensitive to whether `UNICODE` is defined or not (see the definitions in `winuser.h` and `richedit.h`, respectively).  In your case, `UNICODE` is likely defined, in which case your code would actually be calling `CreateWindowW(RICHEDIT_CLASSW, ...)` after being preprocessed.

Comment: CreateWindow is a macro that expands to CreateWindowA or CreateWindowW. Which is it for you? Sounds like the latter. But you need to be clear on the matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So then all I have to do when I set `CreateWindowW(RICHEDIT_CLASSW, ...)` is to change all `SendMessage()`'s to `SendMessageW()`?

Comment: @ASCORE: `SendMessage()` already maps to `SendMessageW()` when `UNICODE` is defined.  You need to change `text` to `wchar_t*` instead.  If that is not an option, then `edit_append()` will have to use `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivalent) to convert the `text` data from Ansi `char*` to UTF-16 `wchar_t*` before then giving that to `SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)`.

Comment: It should be an option, here is my full code: (http://pastebin.com/5cqB4K3G)
Line 101: edit_append()
Line 576: window

Comment: You are using `TCHAR` based Win32 API functions, but passing `char*`-based data to all of them.  That will only work if `UNICODE` is not defined.  In which case, your original code should have worked just fine.  Something else has to be going on.  On a side note - I see you mixing C and C++ code together.  You should stick to C++, such as for string allocations.  For instance, change `edit_append()` to take a `std::string` as input, and `get_text()` to return a `std::string`.

Comment: Nothing in your program indicates the use of Unicode. Are you sure your input data is Unicode? Since you're using `char` and comparing individual bytes to ASCII codes, I'm going to guess it's UTF-8, in which case you'll need to use `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert to UTF-16 on the fly. Windows cannot do UTF-8 in Unicode mode, only UTF-16 (and it can't even do it in ANSI mode, for that matter, for other reasons).

Comment: Here is what I get when I repeatedly put the Unicode character `─` through it: http://imgur.com/TZkOL9J

Comment: None of your code is Unicode-capable to begin with, so why are you trying to run Unicode data through it?  For the record, `â”€` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `─` being displayed as Windows-1252 (or similar charset).

Comment: I figured it would not be that hard to do, but I guess I was wrong lol. Thanks anyways man.

Comment: It's not really that hard but you need to step back and do some learning. Don't expect a quick fix. Start by understand the UNICODE conditional.